# On derivatives of polynomials majorized by $\max(1,|x|^d)$

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory

In the course of generalizing the Bernstein-Markov theorem to normed space, [Harris](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~larry/paper.dir/berns-mark.pdf) came up with the following question.

> Suppose that $p$ is a real polynomial satisfying $|p(x)| \leq (1+|x|)^d$. How large can $|p'(0)|$ be?

Harris obtained a bound of $O(d\log d)$, and [Révész and Sarantopoulos](http://www.renyi.hu/~revesz/HarrisEJA.pdf) gave a matching lower bound $\Omega(d\log d)$.

While attempting a different generalization of the theorem, we encountered the following question:

> Suppose that $p$ is a real polynomial satisfying $|p(x)| \leq \max(1,|x|^d)$. How large can $|p'(1)|$ be?

Our conjecture is that $|p'(1)| = O(d)$. So far we have determined the optima for $d=0,1,2$, which are $0,1,1+\sqrt{2}$, the latter bound attained by
$$ \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right) (x^2 - 1) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} x. $$